# cannot login into Rstudio server (open source) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-20.04, rstudio-server

I installed Rstudio server in ubuntu server 20.04 LTS. The login page appears, but i am not able to login.

I checked `/etc/pam.d/other` and `/etc/pam.d/rstudio` looks alright. Installed java as well.

```
sudo restudio-server status
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-03-02 11:34:34 UTC; 1h 47min ago
    Process: 845 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 956 (rserver)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 7031)
     Memory: 31.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
             └─956 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Java installation is important and the browser shall be either MS edge or Google Chrome.

With me the problem was the internet explorer which didn't allow me to log in.